# Can I take a generator and add a 50amp receptacle to it

Tags: generator

I have a generator that is 9400 watts with a 50amp plug in. No problems running the panel on a food truck. Now I have a whisper generator 9500 watts but only a 30amp plug in. I'm sure it's the 30 vs 50 amp, but I cant get it to run anything. I'm using a 30/50amp converter cord. Can I add a 50amp plug to the whisper generator? Or is there something I'm not connecting right to get the power?

Comment: Think something else is happening than just the plug/receptacle.  Both generators put out a bit less than 40 amps(no 40 amp plugs so they go with 50).  Are you stating the running amps or start up amps?

Comment: Have you checked that "all" the generator's breakers are on?  Imagine that generator has 120 volt receptacle/s, have you tried to plug in something simple like a lamp to see if you get power?

Comment: Be sure they are rated at about the same voltage.

Comment: Also be sure the mfr isn't playing games with statements like "Peak wattage".

Comment: I'm sure it has nothing to do with 30A vs 50A.  Surely something about how your connection is wired. Crossed wire or something like that.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIzBZQr6RVc

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Had one of those hondas(a small one 1200) lent to us for the 98 ice storm.  Ran our 1/2 HP well pump like a dream, with a long 14 gauge cable.  Brought a 5000 amp generator and could only run the well pump if I used 10gauge short cable(~10ft).  Anything less would trip the breakers on the generator.

Comment: Could you describe the symptoms of "can't get it to run anything" a little better? Is there no electric output, or maybe a circuit breaker trips or the engine bogs and stalls when you try to start a load..?